# What could be causing windows service to start slow the first time after changing the logon information?

Tags: windows

I've been changing various internal windows services to use a new domain account logon to get away from using the administrator account. On every server (Server 2003 network), after changing the logon info, the service takes forever to start. The new user is in the Administrator, Domain Administrators, and Users groups. I eventually want to lock it down even more, but I'm having another issue which I'll post separately. After the initial start, the service stops/starts without issues.

I see this warning in the Application event logs.

Windows cannot copy file C:\Documents and Settings\Default User\Application Data\Microsoft\CLR Security Config\v2.0.50727.42\security.config.cch.2368.30046 to location C:\Documents and Settings\production\Application Data\Microsoft\CLR Security Config\v2.0.50727.42\security.config.cch.2368.30046. Possible causes of this error include network problems or insufficient security rights. If this problem persists, contact your network administrator.

DETAIL - Access is denied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would imagine that when the service starts the first time the delay is caused by creation of the local profile for the new account that it runs under.  The error relates to the creation of a new profile for 'production', based on the default user template, and the fact that it's erroring isn't going to help the profile creation speed.

Edit: there's a hotfix for that error with .net 1.0, but not 2: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/842765

Comment: A tad late, but I wanted to give you your due credit. It was definitely the profile creation that was causing the issue. On these servers, the default profile was rather large and never cleaned up. We cleaned up the default profile on all the servers and this fixed it.